# Как вставить чистый текст в блок с contenteditable?

Tags: css3, webkit, html, contenteditable, css

В webkit есть такой баг/фича что при копировании текста где-либо копируется и стиль этого текста. Это хорошо видно на [примере](http://jsfiddle.net/EwCEy/).

Если вы сейчас в хроме или  другом браузере с webkit скопируйте Lorem ipsum в верхнее поле. Тогда вы уведите что стиль текста перенесся в поле.

Если скопированный текст в хроме вставить в это поле только с мозиллы то результат будет тот же.

Если скопировать текст в мозилле и вставить в это поле с любого браузера то текст будет без стиля.

Можно конечно сделать хак чтобы этого не было видно:

```
.t * {
     //тот же стиль текста что и в поле
}
```

Но я хочу чтобы текст вставлялся изначально чистый. Возможно ли что-то сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что при вставке текста, там чудесным образом появляется span, который и стилизует текст внутри себя. Я вижу единственным верным выходом здесь слушать событие input или paste у contenteditable и при возникновении события убирать этот span. Вся проблема в том, что событие input срабатывает до вставки текста в div. Остается только лезть в буфер обмена (об этом ниже).

---

Update: по-моему есть такое решение (смотрите второй ответ): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176861/javascript-get-clipboard-data-on-paste-event-cross-browser/2177059

---

И еще можно почитать здесь http://help.dottoro.com/ljxundda.php

Answer (score 0):

Использовать textarea вместо contenteditable.

Вот зачем сначала брать элемент, который поддерживает форматирование, а потом спрашивать, как его убрать??