# Как вставить чистые элементы в блок с contenteditable (чтобы стили не копировались)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, contenteditable

Здравствуйте, ребята помогите с js пожалуйста, есть `contenteditable` (простой див блок), и когда копируешь например текст с стилями или кнопку например, то оно вставляет в это поле элемент со стилем, не сбрасывает его как в обычных инпутах, как скидывать эти стили подскажите пожалуйста..

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qVmWpE)

Comment: Ничего не понял. Кто куда копирует? Ctrl+C что ли?)

Comment: ** Кого интересует `[нашел вот ответ](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qVmWpE)`
-------------------------------- **

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qVmWpE

Answer (score 1):

```js
var block = document.querySelector(".t");
  

block.oninput = function(){
  var span = document.querySelectorAll(".t span");
  for(var i = 0; i < span.length; i++){
    span[i].style = "";
  }
}
```

```css
.t {
    height: auto;
    min-height: 150px;
    width: 250px;
    border: 1px solid #666;
    background: #eee;
    padding: 5px 7px;
}

.p {
    background: #009baa;
    width: 250px;
    border: 1px solid #666;
    padding: 5px 7px;
}
```

```html
<div class="t" contenteditable></div>
<div class="p">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div><div class="t" contenteditable></div>
<div class="p">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus facilis quod quas magni nemo nam tempora libero optio itaque. Natus!</div>
```

Comment: Будь другом, объясни, что ты понял из вопроса и что значит твой ответ?

Comment: @Air кодпен открой, дальше интуитивно все понятно :)

Comment: в том то и дело, у меня не открылся, простоянно перегружантся

Comment: @Air у него два блока: один обычный с текстом и фоном. Другой contenteditable. Когда из первого копируешь текст во второй (ctrl+c ctrl+v) во второй блок текст вставляется спаном с прописанными инлайн стилями из первого блока.
span появляется только в DOM. я хз как вся эта магия работает.

Comment: @Air скопируй мой код, убери скрипт и попробуй из синего блока скопировать текст в блок с contenteditable. Так понятней будет

Comment: Да я уже понял...  Ну и вопрос)))..  Десять раз перечитал)))) Не понял... Ну ты и голова))))))

Comment: @Air из описания я тоже ничего не понял, пока кодпен не открыл)
И вопрос зачем-то был скопирован. Оказывается такое только с webkit
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/293135/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D1%81-contenteditable?rq=1

Comment: Ребята сорри что объяснил не понятно, буду стараться всё излагать по понятнее )