# Как запретить вставку форматированного текста в contenteditable div?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Допустим, есть

```
<div contenteditable="true"></div>
```

При вставке туда текста с какого-то сайта, одновременно с ним вставляется и его стиль в виде . Как можно фильтровать текст от этой шелухи?

Comment: Не лучше ли использовать textarea? [На английском что-то похожее](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38447285/how-to-prevent-a-contenteditable-div-from-rendering-html)

Comment: Для проекта нужен именно div contenteditable

Comment: Похожие темы [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176861), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/743338)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте через [document.execCommand](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_execcommand.asp) и управляющую команду `inserttext`:

```
$('[contenteditable]').on('paste', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    document.execCommand('inserttext', false, 'ваш_текст_из_буфера_обмена');
});
```

Comment: Если взять за основу этот код, то как очистить буфер обмена от стилей текста прежде чем вставлять его?

Comment: Второй параметр в execCommand, по идее, должен это обеспечивать автоматически. Попробуйте вставить вместо третьего параметра текст со стилями и проверить.

Comment: я хотел уточнить как мне получать скопированные данные, но уже разобрался

Comment: `$('[contenteditable]').on('paste', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
    var pastedData = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text');
    var selection = window.getSelection().toString();
    document.execCommand('inserttext', false, pastedData);
});`