# Как сделать чтобы фон текста не копировался в div

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Копирую текст с какого-либо сайта или редактора, копируется и фон и цвет текста, как это пофиксить?

Comment: Это?) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/989077/Как-запретить-вставку-форматированного-текста-в-contenteditable-div?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дай фону текста user-select: none;
Она запрещает выделить какой-либо текст, значит раз нельзя выделить значит и скопировать нельзя